# Using node_modules in Symfony 6

Tags: symfony, node-modules

I want to use some `node_modules` in my Symfony 6 project. For example, [Feather icons](https://github.com/feathericons/feather#client-side-javascript). But I can't figure out how to include these files without copying them to the public folder or using a CDN.

I have attempted to import the files into `app.js` using:

```
import './feather';
```

Sadly, this does not appear to work. Can anyone help me figure this out because I can also not find any relevant google search results.

**EDIT**
This is what my `app.js` currently looks like:

```
import './styles/app.css';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';
import feather from 'feather-icons'; // <-- added line from comment
```

Comment: Assuming you are using [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html), in `assets/app.js` the path `./feather` would refer to your Symfony `assets/feather` directory. In general you would install the feather-icons assets using `yarn add feather-icons` then in app.js use `import feather from 'feather-icons';` followed by the `feather.replace();` method call. Afterwards recompile the Webpack encore assets `yarn dev`

Comment: @WillB. I did as you said, except I use npm instead of yarn, but I don't think that would make a difference (right?). The console throws this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: feather is not defined`.

Comment: Would depend on if you use Webpack Encore or some other asset manager and `feather.replace();` would also need to be in your app.js file under the `import feather from 'feather-icons';` as that is where the `feather` variable is defined - not available as a global in `<script>`.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I was indeed using Encore, sorry for not mentioning it. I did indeed try to call `feather.replace()` in the DOM instead of in the app.js. Thanks a lot for helping me out here!

Comment: Yea, webpack keeps all of the variables within webpack unless explicitly made global, which makes it difficult to use with legacy libraries, like a lot of jQuery plugins, that make calls directly from the DOM. All of the ES/JS functionality will need to be placed in and compiled from your `assets/*.js` files.